# Is every interval of a connected, totally ordered topological space $X$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As long as connectedness implies linear continuum, then I am induced to think that all intervals of a linear continuum inherit the linear continuum property, and as long as it is an iff statement, they are connected. Can I generalize the proof of $\mathbb{R}$ for a general connected totally ordered space?

Proof:
By contradiction, assume that $J:=[x'',x'] \subseteq X$ is an interval and it is not connected. Let $A,B$ be two nonempty and disjoint closed subsets of $J$ such that $J= A \cup B$. Pick $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ and assume, without loss of generality, that $x \prec y$. As $J$ is an interval, we have $[x,y] \subset J.$ Denote now $U:= A \cap [x,y)$ and $z:= \sup U$. As $U \subset [x,y]$ and $[x,y]$ is closed in $X$ and contained in $J$, it follows that $\overline{U} \subset J$ and so $\overline{U}$ is a closed set in $J$. As $U \subset A$ and $A$ is a closed subset of $J$, it follows that $\overline{U} \subset A$. We can now write that $z \in \overline{U}$ and so $z \in A$. As $z \in [x,y] \cap A$ and $y \in B$, from $A \cap B = \emptyset$ we can write $y \succ z$. Moreover, as $z$ is the supremum of the elements of $A$ that are less than $y$, it follows that $(z,y] \subset B$ and so $z \in \overline{B}$. But now, as $z \in J$ and $B$ is a closed subset of $J$, we have that $z \in \overline{B} \cap J = B$, reaching a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linearly ordered set $X$ in the order topology (a so-called LOTS) is connected iff it is what Munkres calls a linear continuum (every upperbounded set has a supremum and $X$ is order dense). Both of these are inherited by order-convex subsets of $X$ (sets $A$ for which $a < x < a'$ and $a,a' \in A$ implies $x \in A$ always). In particular, closed intervals of connected LOTS's are connected too.

The proof you gave is almost identical to the one that Munkres gives in his text and should indeed closely resemble the one for $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your proof is correct. It works in $R$, but only because you know a supremum exists. But for example take rational numbers. As a subespace of $R$ it is ordered, but the interval (0,2) admits a separation:
$(0,2) \subseteq (0, \sqrt{2}) ∪ (\sqrt{2}, 2)$

So your proof is right but only for complete spaces like real numbers.